# I have an Java Graphql service which i want to consume in Node Express rest service and send the response which I am getting from GraphQl

Tags: express, graphql, middleware

I have an Java Graphql service which i want to consume in Node Express rest service and send the response which I am getting from GraphQl. I have tried with couple of package. But I am not sure this is same as rest service so why it is crashing the node server every time. I am not sure how to integrate with Express js. Do we need a server which listens the qraphql call in Express.?

I haven't added any middleware, I am trying to call the graphql api with the query param.

I want to consume data from a GraphQL API. how can I achieve that?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.